# Conditions for interchanging Ito and Riemannian integrals

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $X_{s,\ r}$ be an adapted real-valued stochastic process, $s,\ r \geq 0$ and $W_s$ be the standard one-dimensional Wiener process (Brownian motion). Under which condition on $X_{s,\ r}$ does the following hold? 
For a fixed $t\geq 0$,
$$\int_0^t\int_0^t X_{s,\ r} dW_s dr = \int_0^t\int_0^t X_{s,\ r} dr dW_s .$$

Thank you!

————————————————

Edit:
Mark Veraar’s comment answers this question.

Comment: Take a look at "The stochastic Fubini theorem revisited" by Mark Veraar: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/17442508.2011.618883?scroll=top&needAccess=true or http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.703.4682&rep=rep1&type=pdf.

Comment: This is indeed helpful. My statement was actually wrong and is now corrected.